# NoMethodError: undefined method ‘describe’ for main:Object error in textmate

Tags: rspec

I am trying to run rspec test but I can't seem to get it to work on my
Mac?

The `player_spec.rb` file contains:

```
require 'player'

describe Player do


end
```

All other related files are in the same folder

Running `rspec player_spec.rb` from the command line generates the
following errors:

```
/Users/lloyd_treleven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
`require': cannot load such file -- player (LoadError)
  from
/Users/lloyd_treleven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
`require'
  from /Users/lloyd_treleven/studio_game/player_spec.rb:1:in `<top
(required)>'
  from
/Users/lloyd_treleven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in
`load'
  from
/Users/lloyd_treleven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in
`block in load_spec_files'
  from
/Users/lloyd_treleven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in
`map'
  from
/Users/lloyd_treleven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in
`load_spec_files'
  from
/Users/lloyd_treleven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in
`run'
  from
/Users/lloyd_treleven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in
`run'
  from
/Users/lloyd_treleven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in
`block in autorun'
```

I have the following rspec gem installed

```
rspec (2.10.0)
rspec-core (2.10.1)
rspec-expectations (2.10.0)
rspec-mocks (2.10.1)
```

Currently I have `rvm 1.13.4` installed

Currently I am running `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]`

When I run the via textmate I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method ‘describe’ for main:Object
```

I installed the RSpec textmate bundle:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Pristine\ Copy/Bundles
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Pristine\ Copy/Bundles
git clone git://github.com/rspec/rspec-tmbundle.git RSpec.tmbundle
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer I needed to have require_relative 'player' at the top of the ruby file?  Once I did this I was able to run rspec player_spec.rb from the command line and have the test execute.  TextMate still throws the NoMethodError error.  I'll check the textmate rspec bundle installation to see if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar recently and it looks like you have 2 problems:

1. A file loading error: rspec can't find your `player.rb` file
2. A missing method error: rspec is confused about who's in charge of
   that `describe` block

Since I'm not sure how your file tree is set up, let's just say it looks like this:

```
/studio_game
  /lib
    player.rb
  /spec
    player_spec.rb
    spec_helper.rb
  Gemfile
  Gemfile.lock
  .rspec
```

To resolve your `LoadError`, you'll need to make sure your `player_spec.rb` file can find your `player.rb` file. You can do that...

```
# like this:
require_relative '../lib/player'

# or like this:
require 'player'
```

Now on to resolving your missing `describe` method error. When I had this problem, I discovered that my `.rspec` file was requiring the `spec_helper`, like this:

```
--require spec_helper  #<-- problematic for me
--color
--format doc
```

Once I removed it, my rspec suite ran correctly.

```
--color
--format doc
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the terminal to access the current subfolder: e.g "lib" or "spec"
I got the same error, and spent a long time to find out that: `cd spec`
then `rspec 00_hello_spec.rb` 
worked for me!